# Since automatic update on ubuntu 13.04, problem loading NVIDIA kernel module

Tags: 13.04, drivers, nvidia, xorg

Since an automatic update which add X server (Xorg), problem on loading NVIDIA kernel module appears. Before Xorg doesn't appear in current process, that's why conclude that Xorg had been added.

Here is the `/var∕log/Xorg.0.log` :

```
[  4931.982]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  4931.986] (EE) NVIDIA: Failed to load the NVIDIA kernel module. Please check your
[  4931.986] (EE) NVIDIA:     system's kernel log for additional error messages.

[  4932.785] (EE) Failed to initialize GLX extension (Compatible NVIDIA X driver not found)
```

Here is my graphic card:

```
$ lspci| grep VGA

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT216M [GeForce GT 320M] (rev a2)
```

dmesg:
whole file [here](http://txtup.co/DvjKT)

```
...
[   20.883670] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[   21.190115] init: nvidia-persistenced main process (1257) terminated with status 1
[   22.037723] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: link down
[   22.037777] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   22.038057] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   23.797388] Bridge firewalling registered
[   24.159079] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
[   24.372053] nf_conntrack version 0.5.0 (16384 buckets, 65536 max)
[   24.583618] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): virbr0: link is not ready
[   25.197600] Ebtables v2.0 registered
[   25.252503] ip6_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
[   25.271254] cgroup: libvirtd (1470) created nested cgroup for controller "memory" which has incomplete hierarchy support. Nested cgroups may change behavior in the future.
[   25.271263] cgroup: "memory" requires setting use_hierarchy to 1 on the root.
[   25.271301] cgroup: libvirtd (1470) created nested cgroup for controller "devices" which has incomplete hierarchy support. Nested cgroups may change behavior in the future.
[   25.271349] cgroup: libvirtd (1470) created nested cgroup for controller "blkio" which has incomplete hierarchy support. Nested cgroups may change behavior in the future.
[   77.508828] vesafb: mode is 640x480x32, linelength=2560, pages=0
[   77.508836] vesafb: scrolling: redraw
[   77.508840] vesafb: Truecolor: size=8:8:8:8, shift=24:16:8:0
[   77.513310] vesafb: framebuffer at 0xd1000000, mapped to 0xffffc90010d80000, using 1216k, total 1216k
[   77.513465] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 80x30
[   77.514707] fb0: VESA VGA frame buffer device

[  167.689216] net_ratelimit: 14 callbacks suppressed
[  167.689267] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_station : Could not get rate (-1)
[  167.689333] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_station : Could not get rssi (-1)
[  167.689436] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_station : Could not get rate (-1)
[  167.690565] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_station : Could not get rssi (-1)
[  168.492108] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[  168.496662] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[  168.497392] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[  168.498869] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
```

Is it possible to solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: You should try uninstalling and reinstalling your NVidia driver. Sometimes it doesn't get built in to the new kernel if it's upgraded.

Comment: The error message tells you what to do. "Please check your system's kernel log for additional error messages." Have a look in `dmesg`.

Comment: @Oli: Ok see my update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the issue. For developpement purpose I had to link gcc into gcc-4.4. 
So to resolve my issue I had to link gcc to my latest: gcc-4.7.
Next basic procedure to reinstall driver works.

Answer (score -1):

I faced similar problem after an upgrade  to 13.04 it was all good until 12.10 version.
I did the following

```
#uninstall the nvidia current driver.**
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current

#use bumblebee 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bumblebee
```

More details can be found [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/bumblebee-321-released-with-ubuntu-1304.html)

HIH

Comment: What does Bumblebee have to do with this question? He does not have an Optimus setup (only one graphics card!).

Comment: @Rohit Kalhans: irrelevant answer.
Any other ideas ?